# SQL Query return one of each

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores
on chat_b_users.id_participante2 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante1 = 1
union all
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores 
on chat_b_users.id_participante1 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante2 = 1 order by last_active DESC
```

how can i select a distinct value?

I need to return all this data even nulls but on of each user, how can i make this?

**results:**

[image]

as you can see in the image, i've two chats from the same user, i only want one of each.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: yes i've tried, same result

Comment: I see, the `DISTINCT` doesn't work because the combination are different. Your timestamp makes them NOT DISTINCT.  Try `MAX` with the `last_active` and see if it helps. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement)

Comment: don't work, where do you want me to put that in the query?

Comment: Try EXCEPT instead of UNION

Comment: i need both results from each query, i've tried and remove one that it should't remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this : add your column list(s) in place of  in the code to identify which row you want to display.

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora
(
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora ,
ROW_NUMBER (PARTITION BY <add_yr_colist> ORDER BY Last_Avtive DESC) AS RNUM 
from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores
on chat_b_users.id_participante2 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante1 = 1 OR id_participante2 = 1
)TVC WHERE RNUM = 1
```

Comment: <add_yr_colist> what is this?

Comment: add a list of the columns which will identify a one particular window.say in your example you need to display message OK for user_Id = 40 , then replace <add_yr_colist> with user_id which will partition the rows in different windows based on user_id values. Hope this explains.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Last_Active DESC)

Comment: SELECT *
(
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora,
ROW_NUMBER (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY last_active DESC) AS RNUM 
from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores
on chat_b_users.id_participante2 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante1 = 1 OR id_participante2 = 1
)TVC WHERE RNUM = 1

|||

still has error

Comment: my mistake! but the erro continues in BY

Comment: well my mistake this time : ROW_NUMBER Should be like this

ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY id_user ORDER BY last_active DESC)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UNIION` instead of `UNION ALL` as below:

```
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores
on chat_b_users.id_participante2 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante1 = 1
union 
select DISTINCT first_name, last_name, picture, last_active, id_participante1, id_participante2, id_user, [message], dataHora from chat_b_users inner join utilizadores 
on chat_b_users.id_participante1 = utilizadores.id_user
left join chat_talks on chat_b_users.id_chat = chat_talks.id_chat
where id_participante2 = 1 order by last_active DESC
```

**UNION removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), UNION ALL does not**.

[Difference betwwen UNION & UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: the same as the other one

Comment: @Severiano As i see there is `message and dataHora ` is different from the previous one. So it is displaying twice.

Comment: it's displaying twice but different messages, if i had 5 messages, it would display 5 times the same user, and i only want the last one

Comment: @Severiano What is the primary key on the table

Comment: id_user is the primary key