# DISTINCT SQL Command

Tags: sql

Update:

```
qid = 1, nick=aa, value=13, time= 20:00:01
qid = 1, nick=bb, value=45, time= 20:00:50
qid = 2, nick=cc, value=77, time= 20:30:50

expected:
qid = 1, nick=bb, value=45, time= 20:00:50
qid = 2, nick=cc, value=77, time= 20:30:50
```

i trying to execute this line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QID FROM "USERNAME"."ANSWER" WHERE Nickname =? ORDER BY Time DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

And I get this error msg:

> The ORDER BY clause may not contain column 'TIME', since the query
>   specifies DISTINCT and that column does not appear in the query
>   result.

What would be the problem?

Comment: The message says it all really, you're not selecting `Time` (just QID) but you try to order by it, which is not allowed with `DISTINCT` queries.

Comment: But i want to order it by time

Comment: Which time do you want to order by? If you for example have 2 rows, `{QID=1, Time=21:00:00}` and `{QID=1, Time=22:00:00}`, the resulting row with your query would be `{QID=1}` but which of the two times should it order by?

Comment: Only the Qid should be distinct

Comment: Yes, but if the only QID is DISTINCT, Time is not. That is, for each QID you have multiple times and need to decide which of them to order by.

Comment: I want to get all fields from the table but if i have 2 columns with same Qid i want to get the last...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in error message you cannot use columns in `distinct` select list when the column is not present in `Order by`

```sql
select * from 
(
select row_number()over(partition by qid Order by Time desc) as Rn,*
From yourtable
) A
Where RN =1
```

Or If your database does not support `ROW_NUMBER` then use this

```sql
SELECT a.* 
FROM   yourtable a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT qid, 
                          Max(time) AS time 
                   FROM   yourtable 
                   GROUP  BY qid) b 
               ON a.qid = b.qid 
                  AND a.time = b.time
```

Comment: As far as I know, `DISTINCT` does not guarantee to keep any order from its input (the subquery)

Comment: it doesnt work for me.. so what can i do if i want to order it and to distinct?

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you don't need `DISTINCT`, you just need to show rows where there exists no newer row with the same QID;

```
SELECT * FROM answer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM answer a
  WHERE answer.qid = a.qid 
    AND answer.time < a.time
)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a630/2).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help you [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement)

If you want use order and distinct use group by.