# How to get distinct polymorphic association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm trying to get show a list of polymorphic relations without having any duplicates.

I have a StoreViews table with a polymorphic field called viewable (so there's a viewable_id and viewable_type column in my table). Now I want to display views with each polymorphic relation showing up just once, without duplicates.

```
@views = StoreView.
    .distinct(:viewable_id)
    .distinct(:viewable_type)
    .order("created_at DESC")
    .limit(10)
```

So if there's two records in StoreViews, both with the same viewable relation, @views should only return the most recent one. However, this is not the case.

Comment: How comes, that you linked the same viewable more than once to the StoreView? Usually you would avoid this using a foreign key constraint, however, that doesn't work for polymorphic associations, instead, you can validate the uniqueness of e.g. the viewable_id using a scope like that:
`validates :viewable_id, uniqueness: { scope: :viewable_type }`, see: [rubyonrails.org#uniqueness](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Answer (score 6):

`ORDER BY` items must appear in the select list if `SELECT DISTINCT` is specified. There are several ways to [work around this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement).

In this example, using an aggregate function should work:

```
@views = StoreView
           .select('DISTINCT viewable_type, viewable_id, MAX(created_at)')
           .group(:viewable_type, :viewable_id)
           .order('MAX(created_at) DESC')
           .limit(10)
```

Answer (score 6):

[`distinct`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) only accept a boolean as a parameter to specify whether the records should be unique or not. So `distinct(:viewable_id)` is equivalent to `distinct(true)` and not doing what you want. Instead of using `distinct`, you should use [`group`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group), which returns an array with distinct records based on the group attribute. To return the most recent one, apart from ordering (with [`order`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)) by `created_at`, you need to add the fields in `group`:

```
@views = StoreView
         .order(viewable_id: :desc, viewable_type: :desc, created_at: :desc)
         .group(:viewable_id, :viewable_type)
```

If you need to have the returned records ordered by `created_at`, you would need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord distinct:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct

> Specifies whether the records should be unique or not. For example:
>
> ```
> User.select(:name)
> # => Might return two records with the same name
>
> User.select(:name).distinct
> # => Returns 1 record per distinct name
> ```

How about this:

```
@views = StoreView
    .select(:viewable_id, :viewable_type)
    .distinct
    .order("created_at DESC")
    .limit(10)
```

You can also try

```
@views = StoreView
    .select('DISTINCT `viewable_id`, `viewable_type`')
    .order("created_at DESC")
    .limit(10)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these worked. I was able to use `StoreView.select('DISTINCT ON (viewable_id, viewable_type) *').order("viewable_id, viewable_type, created_at DESC").limit(10)` and it only shows uniques, however it seems to disregard being ordered by *created_at* ?

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but you can always try to chain this at the end: `.reorder(nil).order(created_at: :desc)` to remove all added `ORDER BY` clauses and then add just one for created at.