# NHibernate Linq OrderBy+Select+Distinct produces invalid SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, nhibernate

If I have these models mapped in NHibernate:

```
public class TagActions {
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangeTime { get; set; }
}
public class Tag {
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

And do the following:

```
// repo.TagActions is IQueryable<TagAction> from session.Query<TagAction>()
var stake = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(120);
repo.TagActions.Where(ta => ta.ChangeTime > stake)
    .OrderByDescending(ta => ta.ChangeTime)
    .Select(ta => ta.Tag).Distinct().Take(10);
```

It produces (in the `MsSql2012Dialect` dialect):

```
    select
        distinct tag1_.Label as label1_12_,
        tag1_.Color as color2_12_
    from
        TagAction tagaction0_
    left outer join
        Tag tag1_
            on tagaction0_.Tag=tag1_.Label
    where
        tagaction0_.ChangeTime>@p0
    order by
        tagaction0_.ChangeTime desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST @p1 ROWS ONLY;
    @p0 = 2020-04-02T10:40:54.0038780Z [Type: DateTime2 (8:0:0)],
    @p1 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]
```

Which is great *except* for the problem that `ChangeTime` does not appear in the `SELECT` clause, so MSSQL fails and rejects the query. The `SQLiteDialect` produces SQL with the same problem, but SQLite processes the query regardless. I am pretty sure that technically MSSQL's response is correct per the SQL spec.

### Question part 1:

This has to be a bug in NHibernate, correct? I did find this:

[MSSql2012Dialect generates invalid order by clause for paging distinct query](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3594)

but it only shows there as applying to 4.0 (alpha) and I'm on 5.2.7. Anyone else have a known bug report on this?

### Question part 2:

Any proposed workaround with `session.Query<TagAction>`/Linq? I am loath to inject `.ToList()` after `OrderByDescending(...)`, which works, but there may be a large number of `TagAction`s and only a small number of `Tag`s to return. Any way to trick it into including the `ChangeTime` column in the `SELECT` clause and still do the `DISTINCT`? I could potentially drop down to HQL or `ICriteria` or something but have no experience with those yet.

Comment: When you distinct you must select the column you are ordening on. A workaround is to group by your Label and Color columns and order by Max change time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in same SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts My key here is using NHibernate and preferably Linq/IQueryable... though since this method is in my repository, if there are no other options I could drop down to HQL or use QueryOver/ICriteria or some other method, if i have to. So no, I understand well the SQL problem, the question is how to get NHibernate to play ball.

Answer (score 0):

For nhibernate you can try something like this with QueryOver:

```
session.QueryOver<TagActions>()
.Select(
    Projections.Group<TagActions>(ta => ta.Label),
    Projections.Max<TagActions>(ta => ta.ChangeTime)
    )
.OrderBy(Projections.Max<TagActions>(ta => ta.ChangeTime)).Desc
.Take(10)
.List<object[]>();
```

Using `Max` because you are sorting descending, and you'll probably want the most recent items.

As far as I know there is no way to accomplish this with linq to nhibernate.
Since you need to `.Select(ta => new { ta.Tag })` you are unable to specify OrderBy on Max(ChangeTime) since it's no longer part of the object.

If you wan't to query with linq, you could create a View/Table valued function with the group by and max() and map this in NHibrenate and query the View/Table valued function with linq.