# How to SQL distinct with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i bring the rows distinctly by OrderID and those who has ProductID 1. if there is no 1 then bring 2

I've tried:

```
Select DISTINCT OrderDetailID,OrderID,ProductID,Quantity from Products 
ORDER BY OrderID,ProductID
```

| OrderDetailID | OrderID | ProductID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10248 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 10248 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10249 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 10250 | 1 | 9 |
| 5 | 10250 | 2 | 40 |
| 6 | 10251 | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | 10252 | 1 | 35 |
| 8 | 10252 | 2 | 15 |
| 9 | 10253 | 2 | 6 |
| 10 | 10254 | 2 | 15 |

Output should be like this:

| OrderDetailID | OrderID | ProductID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10248 | 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 10249 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 10250 | 1 | 9 |
| 6 | 10251 | 2 | 10 |
| 7 | 10252 | 1 | 35 |
| 9 | 10253 | 2 | 6 |
| 10 | 10254 | 2 | 15 |

Comment: See this link please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564/how-to-use-distinct-and-order-by-in-same-select-statement

Comment: I can see every single answer on your questions has not gotten your upvote or approval. This makes questions like this one pop up at the homepage of Stackoverflow because the idea is that there is no answer yet. Could you accept (all other questions you have answers for too) if the answer is useful please? This also motivates others to write answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` to asign ordering to each group of `ProductId`

```
with o as (
select *, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by orderid order by productid) rn
from t
)
select OrderDetailID, OrderID, ProductID, Quantity 
from o
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number` window function

```
select OrderDetailID,OrderID,ProductID,Quantity
from
  select *,row_number()over(partition by OrderID order by OrderDetailID) as seq
  from ) t
where seq = 1
```