# Is there an elegant way to get grouped data by min value and also save ids using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, group-by, query-builder

I have library-like system. In one table bunch of books in different copies and other table for reservations.

**Books** table (for simplisity only three columns)

| id | title | inventory_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coding is awesome | 1111 |
| 2 | Coding is awesome | 2222 |
| 3 | Coding is awesome | 3333 |
| 4 | Get rich quick | 4444 |
| 5 | Get rich quick | 5555 |
| 6 | YOLO | 6666 |

**Reservation** table (for simplisity only three columns)

| id | book_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 |

Although in Books table is 6 books, to end user it means that there is only 3 books - "Coding is awesome", "Get rich quick" and "YOLO" and he don't need to know nothing about other book copies in stock.

When user comes to "Library/Store" and asks for some book than he should get the first book with minimum reservations for current book.

From given data above can be understood that:

- "Coding is awesome" (ID:1) is reserved 2 times
- "Coding is awesome" (ID:2) is reserved 1 times
- "Coding is awesome" (ID:3) is reserved 0 times

So when user asks for "Coding is awesome" book he needs to get book with ID:3
And when he asks for "Get ritch quick" he gets one of two books because all two books is reserved equal number of times.

I need a solution for "end user" that will return only books with different (unique) title and other to current book related data

Although in Books table is 6 books, In this case need to return three books:

| id | title | inventory_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Coding is awesome | 3333 |
| 4 | Get rich quick | 4444 |
| 6 | YOLO | 6666 |

If there will be more books with diferent names then they also need to be shown. (for each unique title one record)

If it is possible then I need to return these data from database using Eloquant or Query Builder not filter out with Collections to save resources and use pagging.

Using Laravel 8, Mysql 5.7

Comment: It's not just the min value need (that's a relatively simple query), but you need min of counts, which is an aggregation of aggregation. What exactly do you mean by getting the answer with eloquent or query builder? Do you mean raw sql statement?

Comment: With eloquent or query builder I mean something like Books::query()... or DB::table('books'). But that is only for "nicer code look". If it's not or hard to achive than raw sql also can be solution

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a `reservations` relationship set up in the `Book` model, using `withCount`, you can get a `reservations_count` for all `books`.

```php
Book::query()
    ->select('id', 'title', 'inventory_number')
    ->withCount('reservations')
    ->get();
```

This will give you a result set like

| id | title | inventory_number | reservations_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coding is awesome | 1111 | 2 |
| 2 | Coding is awesome | 2222 | 1 |
| 3 | Coding is awesome | 3333 | 0 |
| 4 | Get rich quick | 4444 | 0 |
| 5 | Get rich quick | 5555 | 0 |
| 6 | YOLO | 6666 | 0 |

Let's call this `query 1`. You could make something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    -- query 1
) books
GROUP BY id, title, inventory_number
ORDER BY MAX(reservations_count) DESC
```

to get only one relevant row.

In theory, this should work.

```
$query_1 = Book::query()
    ->select('id', 'title', 'inventory_number')
    ->withCount('reservations');

$results = Book::query()
    ->fromSub($query_1, 'books')
    ->groupByRaw('id, title, inventory_number')
    ->orderByRaw('reservations_count ASC')
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();
```

I found something similar at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391564)

---

Another possibility is to use `Collections` to do the hard part.

```
$results = Book::query()
    ->withCount('reservations')
    ->get() // replace with cursor() if you're not using `with()` in the query
    ->sortBy('reservations_count')
    ->unique('title')
    ->take(3); // or ->random(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for fast respons, but using $query_1 and subquery for $result is half of result what I need. It still return all books, but I olny need 3 (with unique titles). And if I undesrtand correctly than with ID column in group by it's not possible to achive.

Comment: You should be able to use a `limit(3)` on the `$results` query for that, or (using collections), use `take(3)` or `random(3)` instead of `values()`.

Comment: I guess I did not fully explain. limit(3) will not help. It's not like I need only three books. I need all available books if there is more than 3. In this example 3 is the unique book count. And by unuque book I mean books with same title.

Comment: It's like in library or shop when you ask for specific book by name than employee brings you one of 10 or 100 available books and you don't know how many of those books actualy are there

Comment: Yeah, this is something completely aside from what you asked and it's not really obvious to me. You should go into a lot more detail on your question by editing it.

Comment: Okay, I edited description, hopefully it will help better understand question and my problem